# Is there a way to register a Gmail account into Online Accounts

Tags: gmail, online-accounts, imap

I noticed today, while trying to develop an application for Ubuntu, that Online Accounts does not provide access to Gmail (I mean access to messages, like IMAP and SMTP), even though it clearly says in the description of the Gmail provider that it does.

Bug reported, but does anyone know of some way I can do that myself? A way to extend the Google provider to also allow access to Gmail?

If there's no way to extend it like that, can someone point me to clear directions on how to add my own service provider for that, because the official documentation looks different from the real thing (no such thing as .service-type files, for example).

Thanks.

Comment: If the answer below has answered your question correctly, please mark it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Online accounts simply provides account details for various accounts. You have to actually implement your own IMAP pull and SMTP send or use a library. Specifying the application you are trying to develop may help here.

UPDATE: APIs

Python API: http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-12.10/python/Accounts-1.0.html

C API: http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-12.10/c/accounts/

Online Accounts Source Code: https://code.launchpad.net/libaccounts-glib

Comment: Hello there. So, I guess I couldn't convey exactly what the problem is. As far as documentations go, I understand that Online Accounts provides access to authentication tokens previously generated via OAuth mechanisms (except for Yahoo!, I guess). As for your question, I'm trying to develop a scope for Unity for searching email attachments (from Gmail, initially). The IMAP part is already half-way done. The only problem is that it relies on login/password, and I want it to use OAuth from Online Accounts.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is that Online Accounts does not ask for access to Gmail emails when doing the authentication (I have already verified it both from the authorization window and from Google's Security preferences-- there's no access to Gmail emails there). The question is: how can I extend the Google provider on Ubuntu to do just that? Is there a way to do it with what's already there or do I have to create a new provider? If I have to, where do I begin? The documentation for that seems a little outdated (as I pointed out earlier). Thanks!

Comment: Try this: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth_overview

Comment: Hello, and thanks again. I've already been there. The problem is not Oauth per se, but how do I get it from Online Accounts. Because I'm doing it from a Scope, I can't ask for the user's permission from there-- I have to rely on Online Accounts for that. The Google part is very well documented and easy to understand. The Online Accounts part is the problem.

Comment: Updated with APIs.